# LiClipse and virtualenv - LiClipse does not know modules from site-packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, liclipse

So I just created a new virtual environment and linked it to a project in LiClipse by setting the interpreter as standard interpreter for the project. The only problem is, that packages installed to the site-packages folder by pip don't seem to be recognized by LiClipse. Is there a step I might have forgotten? I followed this [tutorial](http://ntraft.com/eclipse-with-pydev-and-virtualenv/)

The packages are there in the folder, I used `source activate` before using pip to install the packages.

The folder structure currently looks like this

```
Project
    - src
    - lib
    - bin
    - local
    - share
    - include
```

Comment: What happens when you run the python interpreter for that virtualenv and try to import one of your site-packages?

Comment: It works that way, that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: According to the tutorial you linked to, you should just need to rescan the interpreter. That was bullet point #8. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I did - at least I thought so. Apparently I didn't because now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by PyDev needing to rescan the interpreter to register the site-packages.

OP needed to rescan by going to Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python Interpreters and re-applying the appropriate Interpreter.